# Assignment in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm looking at the following (presumably C++14) piece of code

```
auto min_on = [](auto&& f) {
  return [f=decltype(f)(f)](auto&& arg0, auto&&...args) {
    // call your function here, using decltype(args)(args) to perfect forward
  };
}
```

what is the weird assignment in the lambda capture list? I've never seen an assignment in a capture list

```
f=decltype(f)(f)
```

How does this work?

Comment: When you return a function , you can call it immediately

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's what's called a [Generalized Lambda Capture](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures), and yes, it's C++14.

Basically it allows you to create a new variable as part of the capture list.

Text from link:

> In C++11, lambdas could not (easily) capture by move. In C++14, we have
>   generalized lambda capture that solves not only that problem, but
>   allows you to define arbitrary new local variables in the lambda
>   object. For example:
>
> ```
> auto u = make_unique<some_type>( some, parameters );  // a unique_ptr is move-only
> go.run( [ u=move(u) ] { do_something_with( u ); } ); //move the unique_ptr into the lambda
> ```
>
> In the above example, we kept the
>   name of the variable `u` the same inside the lambda. But we’re not
>   limited to that… we can rename variables:
>
> ```
> go.run( [ u2=move(u) ] { do_something_with( u2 ); } ); // capture as "u2"
> ```
>
> And we can add arbitrary new state to the lambda object, because
>   each capture creates a new type-deduced local variable inside the
>   lambda:
>
> ```
> int x = 4; 
> int z = [&r = x, y = x+1] {
>             r += 2;         // set x to 6; "R is for Renamed Ref"
>             return y+2;     // return 7 to initialize z
>         }(); // invoke lambda
> ```

In your specific instance, you have a lambda that is returning a lambda. The nested lambda is capturing `f` (which was only a parameter in the parent lambda) by using this new syntax.

Comment: I would add that `decltype(f)(f)` in this context is a way of writing `std::forward<T>(f)` since you can't actually name `T`.

Comment: @Brian which `T` are you talking about?

Comment: @Dean the type deduced for the `auto` placeholder.

Comment: @Brian `std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)` would express the intent better.