# How Lambda's members are initalized?

Tags: c++11, lambda

It is said that members of lambda are initialized when lambda is defined not when an object of that lambda has been created. To understand this more I've made a function `foo` that prints a simple message(check of being called later) and returns an integer value ( arbitrary value. here 1024) used to initialize a member of lambda.

Inside the lambda body it prints the value of its captured object.

```
int foo() {
    std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl;
    return 1024;
}

int main() {

    int x = 0;
    [x = foo()]()mutable{ x = foo();  cout << "in un-named lambda x: " << x << endl; };
}
```

The output:

```
foo()
```

Why I get only `foo()` but not:

```
foo()
foo()
in un-named lambda x: 1024
```

- Does this mean `[x = foo()]` is an initialization and in `{x = foo()}` is an assignment?

Comment: You are not calling the lambda. I assume this is a typo.

Comment: @uneven_mark: Does this mean `[x = foo()]` is an initialization?

Comment: `[x = foo()]` is an assignment.  And so is the `x = foo();` inside the body.  Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37952082/2193968\

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It *is* initialization, and I see nothing in that anwser that suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Quentin  Obviously I didn't say what I meant.  What I meant is that x is being assigned a value by running foo().  And the answer I linked to explains why.  I wasn't disagreeing with anyone so I'm not sure which "otherwise" you thought I was making a suggestion about.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah it just looked like you were correcting Itachi by saying that `[x = foo()]` is not an initialization but an assignment. It is still not an assignment though.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: I think `[x = foo()]` is an initialization and not an assignment it is initialization of the member of lambda because it is captured by value. As you can see `lambda` even not called yet but `foo()` is called that is because lambda initialized it memeber from `foo()`. I think the scenario is really similar to initializing any object from a function return value which when control passes through their definition it is initialized. e,g: `int foo(){return 2;} int x = foo();` When control passes the definition of `x`, `foo()` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, there are a couple of problems with your code:

- `int x = 0;`

  this `x` is never used. See below
- `[x = foo()]`

  This does not capture the variable `x` in `main`. Instead it is [a generalized lambda capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952019/assignment-in-lambda). If you want to think in the terms of the class type equivalent of the lambda, it creates a member named `x` initialized with `foo()`. Again absolutely no connection with the variable `x` in main.
- `[x = foo()]()mutable{ x = foo();  cout << "in un-named lambda x: " << x << endl; };`

  And finally your lambda is never called. So `{ x = foo();  cout << "in un-named lambda x: " << x << endl; }` is never executed.

There is this awesome tool which lets you see what transformation the compiler does to your code: https://cppinsights.io/s/cd26f632

```
#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
  std::operator<<(std::cout, "foo()").operator<<(std::endl);
  return 1024;
}


int main()
{
  int x = 0;

  class __lambda_12_5
  {
    int x;
    public: 
    inline /*constexpr */ void operator()()
    {
      x = foo();
      std::operator<<(std::cout, "in un-named lambda x: ").operator<<(x).operator<<(std::endl);
    }

    public: __lambda_12_5(int _x)
    : x{_x}
    {}

  } __lambda_12_5{foo()};

  ;
}
```

---

Also please enable and heed your warnings: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

> ```
> source>:12:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
>
>     [x = foo()]()mutable{ x = foo();  std::cout << "in un-named lambda x: " << x > << std::endl; };
>
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~> ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> <source>:11:9: warning: unused variable 'x' [-Wunused-variable]
>
>     int x = 0;
>
>         ^
>
> 2 warnings generated.
> ```

As you see you are told about both of the unused variable and the not called lambda.